# CRichEditCtrl::StreamIn losing formatting

Tags: c++, mfc, rtf, cricheditctrl

I am creating a `CRichEditCtrl` control and trying to load some RTF into it. The text seems to load fine, but it loses all formatting, essentially becoming plain text.

I think some sample code should suffice to make it clear:

```
class MyWindow : public CWnd {

  void Setup();
  static DWORD CALLBACK StreamInCallback_(
                        DWORD_PTR dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff,
                        LONG cb, LONG *pcb);
  ...
  CRichEditCtrl content_;
};


void MyWindow::Setup() {
  RECT text_rect;
  GetClientRect(&text_rect);
  text_rect.left += 8;
  text_rect.right -= 16;
  text_rect.top += 8;
  text_rect.bottom -= 36;

  content_.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE,
                  text_rect, this, 1001);
  content_.SetTextMode(TM_RICHTEXT);

  CString text = L"{\\rtf1\\par Simple \\b example \\b0}";
  EDITSTREAM es;
  es.dwCookie = reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(&text);
  es.pfnCallback = StreamInCallback_;
  int n = content_.StreamIn(SF_RTF, es);
}

DWORD CALLBACK MyWindow::StreamInCallback_(DWORD_PTR dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff,
                                           LONG cb, LONG *pcb) {
  CString *pText = reinterpret_cast<CString *>(dwCookie);

  if (cb > pText->GetLength()) {
    cb = pText->GetLength();
  }

  // TODO: this will only work for US-ASCII
  for (int i = 0; i < cb; i++) {
    *(pbBuff + i) = (BYTE) pText->GetAt(i);
  }

  *pcb = cb;
  *pText = pText->Mid(cb);

  return 0;
}
```

You can see an example of what this looks like in the screenshot below:

[image]

As you can see, it's got the text OK, but the word "example" should be bold. I've tried lots of different RTF, even taking what's saved by Wordpad and using that directly, but it still only displays the text as plain text and all formatting is lost. No errors are returned from any of the function calls, either.

Answer (score 1):

Sure looks correct to me. Though, I've never used `SetTextMode(TM_RICHTEXT)` when dealing with RTF content. Try removing that call.

Also, an erroneous `StreamInCallback` may yield weird text problems. I suggest you do it the right way from start:

```
DWORD CALLBACK CBStreamIn(DWORD dwCookie, LPBYTE pbBuff, LONG cb, LONG *pcb)
{
    CString *pstr = (CString*)dwCookie;

    if (pstr->GetLength() < cb)
    {
        *pcb = pstr->GetLength();
        memcpy(pbBuff, (LPCSTR) *pstr, *pcb);
        pstr->Empty();
    }
    else
    {
        *pcb = cb;
        memcpy(pbBuff, (LPCSTR) *pstr, *pcb);
        *pstr = pstr->Right(pstr->GetLength() - cb);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although it doesn't quite work for me since my program is compiled with `UNICODE` so streaming Unicode from here wasn't working. I did end up changing it to `WideCharToMultiByte` from what I had in the question, but that still didn't fix it. In the end, I actually figured out the problem was that I was calling `SetFont` on the `CRichEditCtrl` *after* streaming the content in (a left-over from when I was using a plain EDIT control)... d'oh!

Answer (score 0):

Try if setting headers in the RTF works. Check following link

http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm

Check if this works in your richeditctrl.

```
{\\rtf1\\ansi\\deff0{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Calibri;}}\\par Simple \\b example \\b0}
```